# Insert element at every nth location in list of lists

Tags: python, list, append

I'm working on a project in Python and came across a problem. 
I have a long data set that is a list of two ply lists that looks like this:

```
[('A', 15), ('C', 125), ('L', 37), ('J', 215), ('M', 829), etc.]
```

What I want to do is insert another data set that has the same first element but a different second like this:

```
[('A', 2), ('C', 4), ('L', 9), ('J', 7), ('M', 15), etc.]
```

so that the first set of data has three elements to each list, like this:

```
[('A', 15, 2), ('C', 125, 4), ('L', 37, 9), ('J', 215, 7), ('M', 829, 15), etc.]
```

What kind of code would I need to set up to get this third set of data to add its second element to my first set of data?

Comment: Can you provide more information, i.e., are the first two lists of equal size? Are the letters unique?

Comment: If the letters are unique and act as a key this would be better refactored as a dictionary

Answer (score 2):

If this is by position and the lists have equal length, you can try this:

```py
l1 = [('A', 15), ('C', 125), ('L', 37), ('J', 215), ('M', 829)]
l2 = [('A', 2), ('C', 4), ('L', 9), ('J', 7), ('M', 15)]

l_combined = [(i[0][0], i[0][1], i[1][1]) for i in zip(l1, l2)]
```

What you basically do is to combine both lists into a larger tuple, where you then access each element by position.

Comment: This will work as long as both lists always contain all the elements, which does appear to be the implication. If so it's a nice use of the zip function to keep things concise.